# How to create a git repository on my server from the github server?

Tags: git, github, repository

I admit the question isn't crystal clear..

I am cloning a github hosted project(askbot).
I want to create my private repository for this project so that my team members can make modifications.

> I also want to be able to fetch(or pull) new updates from the original
>   github repository(the project will have new features and bug fixes and
>   so on)

In short, I want a repository that we can push/pull privately and that we can also pull from the original github repository.
Are there special setup needed for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git clone` will create a full fledged repository. you can work at it, pull from it and push changes to it.

The only problem is, that you cannot push to the currently checked out branch. To solve this you can set up a `--bare` repository, which has no branch checked out.

You also have to decide, how to access you repository. You can use ssh, git-daemon, or a wrapper like gitolite.

On your working copy you can set up two remotes. One for the upstream and one you your clone.
This allows you to fetch updates from upstream, merge them in your own work, and push it back to your clone.

Hence:

- decide where to put your private repository and how to access it
- use `git clone --bare $upsteam` to create the private repository
- Clone your working copy for the private repository, creating remote "origin"
- use `git remote add` to add another remote "upstream"
- have fun

Comment: Thank you first.  1. I'm going to follow http://kovshenin.com/2011/howto-remote-shared-git-repository/ 2. git clone --bare git://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel.git ? what's `$upstream`? 3. Clone your `working copy` for the private repository. I don't get this sentence

Comment: forgot to mention your name, can you take a look at my comment?

Comment: $upstream is just a placeholder for your URL. - In you case "git://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel.git", as you already did correctly. You clone your server copy from upstream and you working copy from the server. The working copy ist on the host you develop on.