# connect my local git repository with github forked repository?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I created my private & local repository using `git clone --bare $upstream` 
(detailed here [How to create a git repository on my server from the github server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332586/how-to-create-a-git-repository-on-my-server-from-the-github-server))

At that time, I didn't think I will be contributing to the original github repo. ($upstream)
And I found out that **pull requests** is only possible from github repository.

So my question is **How can I contribute to the original github repo?**

I wonder if following strategy is possible:

> 1. I create a github fork from $upstream (the original opensource github
>      repo)
> 2. somehow teach my local repo about the new github fork(as I did `git remote add`)
> 3. create a branch(MyWork) on my local clone, work, and push to the new github fork
> 4. pull requests to original repo auther.

**Edit**

Since there are many modifications(commits) in my private repo,
**I need a way to go to the current $upstream's clean state**(upstream's master without my local modification which I made in my origin/master , not in MyWork).

(So that my pull request doesn't have my modification except the branch(for pull request))

How can I do that?

Comment: The steps you suggested are correct - step 2 would be `git remote add <somename> git@github.com:my/fork.git`

Comment: user1615903, can you look at my edit?

Comment: Assuming you have remotes `upstream` (the original repository) and `mygithub` (the fork), you can `git fetch upstream` as usual to get their clean state, then rebase your work in a branch `mywork` onto it, i.e. onto `upstream/master`, then finally `git push mygithub mywork`. – Are your local changes in the branch called `master` or in a different branch?

Comment: @chirlu: my local changes are in master@origin (origin is my local server)

Comment: Does it affect workflow here? Please enlighten me if my workflow is sub-optimal

Comment: Well, the suboptimal thing was that you thought you would never want to upstream anything. :) But everything is fixable.

Comment: haha... :( .. I 'm still not done with this. How do I deal with the changes I made in my local master? Since when I branched off MyWork, master had commits which were not present in upstream/master. How do I contribute only MyWork part? (I took a deep breath and did rebase upstream/master from MyWork. and it conflicted..)

Comment: don't I need to git merge upstream/master after git fetch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

took me a long time to figure it out..
There's a `cherry-pick` command in git which is perfect for my situation.

[Send a pull request on GitHub for only latest commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256021/send-a-pull-request-on-github-for-only-latest-commit?rq=1)

basically,

```
git checkout -b MyWork_for_pull_request upstream/master (make branch off upstream/master not origin/master)
git cherry-pick `sha-of-MyWork-branch's-commit` (pick out commits I want to contribute)
git push mygithub_fork MyWork_for_pull_request
```

and press `pull request` in the github page.